# How to check if the current time is between two times?

Tags: postgresql

[postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) documentation gives an example `timerange` definition:

```
CREATE FUNCTION time_subtype_diff(x time, y time) RETURNS float8 AS
'SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (x - y))' LANGUAGE sql STRICT IMMUTABLE;

CREATE TYPE timerange AS RANGE (
  subtype = time,
  subtype_diff = time_subtype_diff
);

SELECT '[11:10, 23:00]'::timerange;
```

The problem is that when time crosses the day barrier, the range can no longer be used, e.g.

```
SELECT '[22:00, 06:00]'::timerange;
```

will produce an error:

```
ERROR:  range lower bound must be less than or equal to range upper bound
LINE 1: SELECT '[22:00, 06:00]'::timerange;
```

I need to be able to check if the current time is between 22:00 today and 06:00 tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

Solution 1:

Define the range column as 'hours since midnight'. Continuing with the 22:00 and 06:00 range example, the range value would be `[22, 30]` (22 hours since midnight, 1 day + 6 hours since midnight), i.e.

```
current_date::timestamptz + interval '22 hours' AND
current_date::timestamptz + interval '30 hours'
```

One could define a custom rangetype for this purpose.

Solution 2:

Alternatively, you can have two columns:

```
maintenance_window_starts_at time without time zone
maintenance_window_duration interval
```

and write the check as:

```
SELECT
  maintenance_window_starts_at IS NULL OR
  now() BETWEEN
    current_date + maintenance_window_starts_at AND
    current_date + maintenance_window_starts_at + maintenance_window_duration
FROM maintenance_task;
```

Both solutions were suggested by the members of Freenode #postgresql community.

Comment: beware that solution 2 still requires handling cross-day intervals; (23:00, 01:00) and current datetime 2018-12-31 00:30 would be transformed to `2018-12-31 00:30 BETWEEN 2018-12-31 23:00 AND 2019-01-01 01:00`

Answer (score 1):

A [range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rangetypes.html) require a lower-bound and an upper-bound, [time data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html) allows values:

```
+------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------------------+
| Name                               | Storage Size | Description                       | Low Value     | High Value    | Resolution                |
+------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------------------+
| time [ (p) ] [ without time zone ] | 8 bytes      | time of day (no date)             | 00:00:00      | 24:00:00      | 1 microsecond / 14 digits |
+------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------------------+
| time [ (p) ] with time zone        | 12 bytes     | times of day only, with time zone | 00:00:00+1459 | 24:00:00-1459 | 1 microsecond / 14 digits |
+------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------------------+
```

In fact in your example: `22:00 till 06:00`. Is it 06:00 of next day or two days after tomorrow?

If you need to cross this boundaries, you should use another data type:

- tsrange   : Range of timestamp without time zone
- tstzrange : Range of timestamp with time zone
- daterange : Range of date

Answer (score 1):

use two columns,

```
select (x <= start_time) <> (x <= end_time) <> (start_time < end_time) as x_between
```